# Abstract typed array construction JIT performance

Tags: julia

In one of my application, I have to store elements of different subtypes in the array and I got big hit by the JIT performance.
Below is a minimal example.

```
abstract A
immutable B <: A end
immutable C <: A end

b = B()
c = C()
@time getindex(A, b, b)
@time getindex(A, b, c)
@time getindex(A, c, c)
@time getindex(A, c, b)
@time getindex(A, b, c, b)
@time getindex(A, b, c, c);

  0.007756 seconds (6.03 k allocations: 276.426 KB)
  0.007878 seconds (5.01 k allocations: 223.087 KB)
  0.005175 seconds (2.44 k allocations: 128.773 KB)
  0.004276 seconds (2.42 k allocations: 127.546 KB)
  0.004107 seconds (2.45 k allocations: 129.983 KB)
  0.004090 seconds (2.45 k allocations: 129.983 KB)
```

As you see, each time I construct the array for different combination of elements, it has to do a JIT.

I also tried `[...]` instead of `T[...]`, it appeared worse.

Restart the kernel and run the following:

```
b = B()
c = C()
@time Base.vect(b, b)
@time Base.vect(b, c)
@time Base.vect(c, c)
@time Base.vect(c, b)
@time Base.vect(b, c, b)
@time Base.vect(b, c, c);

  0.008252 seconds (6.87 k allocations: 312.395 KB)
  0.149397 seconds (229.26 k allocations: 12.251 MB)
  0.006778 seconds (6.86 k allocations: 312.270 KB)
  0.113640 seconds (178.26 k allocations: 9.132 MB, 3.04% gc time)
  0.050561 seconds (99.19 k allocations: 5.194 MB)
  0.031053 seconds (72.50 k allocations: 3.661 MB)
```

In my application I face a lot of different subtypes: each element is of type `NTuple{N, A}` where `N` can change. So in the end the application was stuck in JIT.

What's the best way to get around it? The only way I can think of is to create a wrapper, say `W`, and box all my element into `W` before entering the array. So the compiler only compiles the array function once.

```
immutable W
    value::NTuple
end
```

Thanks to @Matt B. after overloading his `getindex`,

```
c = C()
@time getindex(A, b, b)
@time getindex(A, b, c)
@time getindex(A, c, c)
@time getindex(A, c, b)
@time getindex(A, b, c, b)
@time getindex(A, b, c, c);

  0.008493 seconds (6.43 k allocations: 289.646 KB)
  0.000867 seconds (463 allocations: 19.012 KB)
  0.000005 seconds (5 allocations: 240 bytes)
  0.000003 seconds (5 allocations: 240 bytes)
  0.004035 seconds (2.37 k allocations: 122.535 KB)
  0.000003 seconds (5 allocations: 256 bytes)
```

Also, I realized the JIT of tuple is actually quite efficient.

```
@time tuple(1,2)
@time tuple(b, b)
@time tuple(b, c)
@time tuple(c, c)
@time tuple(c, b)
@time tuple(b, c, b)
@time tuple(b, c, c);
@time tuple(b, b)
@time tuple(b, c)
@time tuple(c, c)
@time tuple(c, b)
@time tuple(b, c, b)
@time tuple(b, c, c);

  0.000004 seconds (149 allocations: 10.183 KB)
  0.000011 seconds (7 allocations: 336 bytes)
  0.000008 seconds (7 allocations: 336 bytes)
  0.000007 seconds (7 allocations: 336 bytes)
  0.000007 seconds (7 allocations: 336 bytes)
  0.000005 seconds (7 allocations: 352 bytes)
  0.000004 seconds (7 allocations: 352 bytes)
  0.000003 seconds (5 allocations: 192 bytes)
  0.000004 seconds (5 allocations: 192 bytes)
  0.000002 seconds (5 allocations: 192 bytes)
  0.000002 seconds (5 allocations: 192 bytes)
  0.000002 seconds (5 allocations: 192 bytes)
  0.000002 seconds (5 allocations: 192 bytes)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The JIT heuristics here could probably be better tuned in the base library.  While Julia does default to generating specialized methods for unique permutations of argument types, there are a few escape hatches you can use to reduce the number of specializations:

- Use `f(T::Type)` instead of `f{T}(::Type{T})`. Both are well-typed and behave nicely through inference, but the former will only generate one method for all types.
- Use the undocumented all-caps `g(::ANY)` flag instead of `g(::Any)`. It's semantically identical, but `ANY` will prevent specialization for that argument.

In this case, you probably want to specialize on the type but not the values:

```
  function Base.getindex{T<:A}(::Type{T}, vals::ANY...)
       a = Array(T,length(vals))
       @inbounds for i = 1:length(vals)
           a[i] = vals[i]
       end
       return a
   end
```

Comment: If I want to write a function `test(vals::ANY...)`, is it possible to also assert that `vals...` must be of type `A`

Comment: No, not within the method signature, as far as I'm aware.  You can do so in the method body, though.  And in this case, assigning to an element of the array of type `T` will try to convert any non-`A` values. It'll throw an error if there isn't a conversion defined.